# How do i get all columns / rows from my Database [VB.Net/MariaDB]

Tags: vb.net, mariadb, mysql.data

I am trying to get all results with the MySQL.Data Nuget because I am using MariaDB. But my Method just provides the first entry in my DB and does nothing more.

```vb
Public Function getAllFields(ByVal sql As String) As List(Of String)
        Dim output As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

        Using cn = New MySqlConnection(connString.ToString())

            Using cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, cn)
                cn.Open()

                Using rd = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    rd.Read()

                    Dim objs(rd.FieldCount) As Object
                    Dim quant As Integer = rd.GetValues(objs)
                    Dim i As Integer
                    For i = 0 To quant - 1
                        output.Add(objs(i))
                    Next i
                    rd.Close()
                End Using

                cn.Close()
            End Using
        End Using

        Return output

    End Function
```

Comment: can you try this `While rd.Read() /*Codes*/ End While`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `rd.Read` returns `True` when data is read, and `False` otherwise. So you need to loop until it returns `False`.

```
Using rd = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    While rd.Read()
        Dim objs(rd.FieldCount) As Object
        Dim quant As Integer = rd.GetValues(objs)
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To quant - 1
            output.Add(objs(i))
        Next i
    End While
End Using
```